# Agrupar resultados por el máximo de fecha

Tags: sql

Tengo una tabla que puede contener referencias duplicadas, y lo que tengo que obtener es es la última versión de ese dato.

- **Referencia**: id del dato
- **Estado**: situación en la que se encuentra (A o F)
- **Fecha**: mes en el que se ha cargado el dato

Así por ejemplo, la tabla podría tener estos resultados de cada mes del primer trimestre:

| Referencia | Estado | Fecha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA1 | A | 2022-01-31 |
| AAA1 | F | 2022-02-28 |
| AAA1 | A | 2022-03-31 |

Lo que quiero conseguir es que mi consulta me devuelva el último mes, es decir, el dato perteneciente al mes `2022-03-31`, cuyo estado es **A**.

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
select
    REFERENCIA,
    ESTADO,
    max(FECHA) as FECHA
from (
    select
        REFERENCIA,
        ESTADO,
        FECHA
    from
        TABLA
    where
        REFERENCIA = 'AAA1'
        and FECHA between '2022-01-31' and '2022-03-31'
    )
group by REFERENCIA, ESTADO
```

Pero los resultados que me devuelve son estos:

| Referencia | Estado | Mes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA1 | F | 2022-02-28 |
| AAA1 | A | 2022-03-31 |

Y creo que es porque como encuentra en Estado dos valores diferentes los agrupa.

La solución podría pasar por filtrar los estados sea igual a F, pero para el modelo que estoy creando esto sería incorrecto, porque es cierto que sólo obtendría un valor, pero sería el de febrero que está a F, pero necesito que en este caso no lo contara.

Es decir, para este caso, necesito que obtenga el máximo de la fecha, pero que además, sólo si está F, es decir, que para este caso no tendría que devolverme nada los resultados, pero la realidad es que obtengo dos referencias.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: En caso de que quieras que tevuelva solo el del F, lo tendrás que añadir en el `where`, por otra parte, si solo quieres que te muestre el de la fecha más alta, puedes probar a ordenarlo por fecha, y al final de tu consulta poner `limit 1` para que solo te enseñe el da le fecha más alta

Comment: Si pongo en el **where** los estados F, me devolvería el de febrero, pero obviaría la última versión de marzo, que está en A.

Comment: @David, en bases de datos un ejemplo ayuda más que las explicaciones, que también vienen bien, pero son muy difíciles de seguir... Pásanos el dataset en SQL (para poder reproducir el escenario) y el resultado que esperarías para esos datos de muestra y seguro que entenderemos mucho mejor lo que necesitas. ¿Con qué sistema gestor trabajas? ¿MySQL?

Comment: Cierto @DavidJP, tendría que haber añadido un pequeño dataset, pensaba que con el ejemplito era suficiente. Aún así ya he dado con la solución, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final di con la siguiente solución, donde en la primera consulta obtengo el máximo de las fechas, y en la siguiente, aquellos que sean F.

De esta forma me funciona, ¡gracias!

```
select
    REFERENCIA,
    ESTADO,
    max(FECHA) as FECHA
from
    TABLA A
where
    FECHA = (
             select
                 max(FECHA )
             from
                 TABLA B
             where
                 A.REFERENCIA = B.REFERENCIA
                 and FEC_REFERENCIA between '2022-01-31' and '2022-03-31'
             )
and ESTADO= 'F'
```

Answer (score 0):

te comentaria pero necesito mas reputacion asi que te lo escribo por aqui, has probado a hacer un  top 1 de la fecha que en tu caso es max(fecha), de esta manera te sacara la fecha mas mayor o mas reciente que encuentre

Quedaria tal que asi, dime si te funciona

```
select top 1 (FECHA) as FECHA, REFERENCIA, ESTADO from ( select REFERENCIA, ESTADO, FECHA from TABLA where REFERENCIA = 'AAA1' and FECHA between '2022-01-31' and '2022-03-31' ) group by REFERENCIA, ESTADO
```

Comment: Bienvenido Pablo, ¿podrías editar tu pregunta y añadir tu posible solución incluyendo el código de cómo quedaría? Te lo agradecería, gracias!

Comment: select
    top 1 (FECHA) as FECHA,
 REFERENCIA,
    ESTADO
    
from (
    select
        REFERENCIA,
        ESTADO,
        FECHA
    from
        TABLA
    where
        REFERENCIA = 'AAA1'
        and FECHA between '2022-01-31' and '2022-03-31'
    )
group by REFERENCIA, ESTADO

Comment: Tambien puede ser que no especifiques la hora entonces por tema de la hora no te este cogiendo la ultima fehca, prueba a en vez de hacer un between de '2022-01-31' and '2022-03-31' a esto '2022-01-31' and '2022-04-01', mas que nada por verificar si ese era el fallo

Comment: Estás agregando la verdadera respuesta en los comentarios. Borra el ruido en tu respuesta actual, y pon el código que pusiste en el comentario como respuesta. Tampoco olvides explicar tu respuesta: lee [answer]. Por último, no desesperes si no puedes dejar aún comentarios: si haces buenos aportes, podrás tener la reputación suficiente como para comentar próximamente.

Comment: @padaleiana ya he añadido el codigo, muchas gracias